# How to store Pincode filed in SOLR and how can I retrieve data according to the pincode?

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I have a Pincode field like "389151" and I want to store this in below format.

pincode_analyzed: [
"389151",
"38915",
"3891",
"389"
]

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the Pincode field to the pincode_analyzed field defined with a fieldType similar to this:

```
<fieldType name="text_general_edge_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="6" side="front" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

`<field name="pincode_analyzed" type="ngrams" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />`

`<copyField source="Pincode" dest="pincode_analyzed"/>`

You can read more about tokenizers here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers

Comment: This seems to be fine. But how can I retrieve data according to that? like if I want products for pincode " 389001 " then also i want these results because these are similar to the pincode.For this pincode I want exact match first then the pincodes starts with 38900, then 3890 and last which starts with 389. How is this possible?

Comment: I added the `<analyzer type="query">...</analyzer>` which will also tokenize on query. I think you can do a search with `q=389151*` which will return results as you said above.

Comment: There is some error in your code. You cannot add two <tokenizer> in one <field type> and and you should add <filter> in <tokenizer> and I am trying like this but not working.

Comment: <fieldType name="text_general_edge_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="6" side="front"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

Comment: Actually I used analyzer tool and it is showing right.But the data is not stored like I want.But get results accordingly